# How to define objects in if-else statements in Swift?

Tags: swift

I want to define an object a certain way if a condition is met, or define it as a different object of the condition is not met. However, when I try to use that object later in my code, it doesn't recognize it as being defined.

I want something like this

```
if condition {
    object = Class1()
} else {
    object = Class2()
}
```

Comment: @LinusGeffarth If you think the question is ambiguous, then vote to close it as unclear.

Comment: Fair point, I just thought it'd make more sense to clear up the ambiguity myself since it's clear from the text in the question, but the code doesn't reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to declare your variable earlier:

```
let object: RootClass
if condition {
    object = Class1()
} else {
    object = Class2()
}
```

where `RootClass` is a type that can represent both `Class1` and `Class2`.

Swift's definitive initialization rules will ensure that `object` gets exactly one value on every path where it is used.

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. Even though I've subclassed my 2 options, it won't let me assign the value of Class1 to type RootClass. Is there something else I need to change to tell it how to change classes?

Comment: @Kayan , you will need to show at least how the two classes are defined (just the `class Class1 ... {` line and the error that you get.

Answer (score 1):

If for some odd reason your Class1 and Class2 are not related you can do something like this

```
var object: Any
if condition {
    object = "something"
} else {
    object = 32
}
```

and later use it as

```
if let some = object as? Int {
    //do int stuff
} else if let some = object as? String {
    //do string stuff
}
```

Comment: You know, you don't have to make `object` optional, since you assign it in every possible path. Just do `var object: Any` instead.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth True, that is just a playground requirement.

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple ways to do it, In `Swift` Type has to match, so can't assign two different type of classes based on condition for same object, so either use `Protocol`(more swifty) or `Inheritance`

**1. Use protocols: lets declare a protocol `MyProtocol`, both `Class1` and `Class2` both confirms to**

```
protocol MyProtocol { }

class Class1: MyProtocol { }
class Class2: MyProtocol { }
```

Now, when initialising object:

```
var object: MyProtocol
if condition {
    object = Class1()
} else {
    object = Class2()
}
```

or:

```
let object = condition ? Class1() : Class2()
```

**2. Use Inheritance**

```
class MainClass() { }

class Class1: MainClass { }

class Class2: MainClass { }

let object = condition ? Class1() : Class2()
```

**3. Use Any type**

```
let object: Any = condition ? Class1() : Class2()

if object is MyClass1 {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
let object = condition ? Class1() : Class2()
```

You can alternatively declare the `object` as an `optional` and `var` & you can assign a value to it later.

Comment: Your code behaves exactly as the one from the question, so how does it solve the problem?

Comment: @Cristik why is that? It's not inside any braces, so problem fixed - except if the OP's if-else is more complex than what they shared.

Comment: So you're saying OP's problem is related to braces? Hope not :)

Comment: I'm guessing the OP wants to use the object outside the if-else statement. He can't do that, if he declares it inside the braces, which is why zneak's answer works. If there's no need for an if-else statement in the first place, then this answer works just fine.

Comment: Same applies to Anji's answer below, which is literally the same.

Comment: This answer does not declare `var object =`  or `let object =`  so presumably that happens elsewhere? How is object declared?

Comment: @Magnas from the OP's question, it seems like `object` has been declared before - which in fact, would make their question irrelevant, so probably, they just left this part out of the post. –– I've updated the question to make this clearer.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth did you just change the wording of the code in the question

Comment: @Cristik from OP's question, it appeared they wanted to use the object outside of braces, which otherwise wouldn't have been possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
let classsObject =  condition ? Class1() : Class2()
```

Here after `?` your condtion is  right and after `:` your else part

Comment: Your code behaves exactly as the one from the question, so how does it solve the problem?